# Boolean algebra simplification using theorems of Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean, algebra

The Boolean function that I need to simplify is:

VW + VWX'Y + VWYZ' + VWX'Z + X'YZ

To start off, I first factored out VW to get:

VW (1+X'Y+YZ'+X'Z)+X'YZ

At this point I am stuck. I tried factoring out an X' from the expression to get:

VW (1+YZ'+X'(Y+Z)) 
but I feel this is wrong, as I can't figure out where to go from here.

Any hints on what the next step should be?

Answer (score 1):

1. 1 + X'Y + YZ'+ X'Z = 1 (Law of Union)
2. VM * 1 = VM (Law of Intersection)

So, VW(1+X'Y+YZ'+X'Z) + X'YZ = VW + X'YZ

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, what exactly is the law of union?

Comment: @user3502200, The law of union consists of two simplifications: 1) A + 1 = 1, 2) A + 0 = A. In this example A = X'Y + YZ'+ X'Z.